# Is there any way to make sprintf() not delete 0's when taking ints as input?

Tags: c, string, integer, printf, scanf

Hey there so I have this code to convert three separate integers into a single string

```
scanf("%d, %d:%d:%d, %d, %d", &pID, &tStmpHr, &tStmpMin, &tStmpSec, &cond, &reading);
sprintf(timeS, "%d:%d:%d", tStmpHr, tStmpMin, tStmpSec);
```

Its going to take in ints between 0 and 59, the issue I am having is that if it takes in an int less than 10 the sprintf will delete the zero before the actual integer. The scanf doesnt seem to cause this issue, and I believe the reason this is happening is because sprintf thinks these digits (say 09 for an example) are the same without the zero (09 == 9) so is there any way to make sprintf not delete these zeros when taking it into he string?

Edit: just to clarify on how I want the string to come out vs how its currently coming out:

```
tStmpHr = 11
tStmpMin = 08
tStmpSec = 01
```

What's currently coming out

```
11:8:1
```

What I want to come out

```
11:08:01
```

Comment: -1: `sprintf(timeS, "%02d:%02d:%02d", tStmpHr, tStmpMin, tStmpSec);`

Comment: You really should also have provided the input you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf` does not "delete" zeroes. You have not provided it any leading zeroes. The values you are passing in are integers, and have no concept of formatting built into them.

`sprintf`'s format string tells it how to output the values.

In your case, you want each value zero-padded to two digits, so for each value:

```
 %02d
```

Where

- `0` is a flag meaning "zero padding"
- `2` is the field width
- `d` is the conversion specifier for an integer in signed decimal notation

All of this is explained in the `sprintf` man page. Next time you have a question about a C function, try reading the man page!

Answer (score 2):

As pmg pointed out in the comment, you can format the output of sprintf by adding an 0 after % to indicate that it should print leading zeros.

The following 2 means the field width should be 2.

```
sprintf(timeS, "%02d:%02d:%02d", tStmpHr, tStmpMin, tStmpSec);
```